# TTTAttributedLabel:Crash-tapping on link. [NSConcreteAttributedString reverseObjectEnumerator]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8eb7f60'

Tags: ios, hyperlink, uilabel, nsattributedstring, tttattributedlabel

Working on a chat application. Using TTTAttributedLabel in my custom Cell. So that i can detect links. I implemented that code in my custom cell.

```
    self.tttAttributedLabel=[[TTTAttributedLabel alloc] init];
    self.tttAttributedLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
    self.tttAttributedLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    self.tttAttributedLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    self.tttAttributedLabel.linkAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge NSString *)kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName];
    self.tttAttributedLabel.enabledTextCheckingTypes = NSTextCheckingTypeLink; 
    self.tttAttributedLabel.delegate = self;
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.tttAttributedLabel];
```

i am getting crash in below function. I dont know why there is crash. it seems like self.links is not a valid array.

```
  - (NSTextCheckingResult *)linkAtCharacterIndex:(CFIndex)idx
{
     NSEnumerator *enumerator = [self.links reverseObjectEnumerator]; //crash on this 
   NSTextCheckingResult *result = nil;
   while ((result = [enumerator nextObject])) {
    if (NSLocationInRange((NSUInteger)idx, result.range)) {
        return result;
    }
}
return nil;
}
```

[image: Chat]

Comment: I would put a break point at `- (void)setLinks:(NSArray *)links` and then do a back trace to see what is called prior.  From there work back until you figure out where `self.links` is being set.

Comment: did you figure out a solution? I'm having the same problem and the links NSArray seems to be losing reference

Comment: @kevinl Not to plug my own answer here, but the issue (as I mention below) is that `init` is not the correct designated initializer; you must use `initWithFrame:`. Otherwise, the links property will not be initialized.

Comment: @JonathanHersh Thanks Jonathan. However, I've been using initWithFrame.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the designated initializer, `initWithFrame:`, even if you pass in `CGRectZero` as the frame. You are using `init`, which will not perform the common initialization method that initializes the `links` property.